# Exception handling with python

Tags: python

Hi guys am just a beginner in python.I studied about exception handling and it found so difficult for me. My code is

```
def exceptionhandling(z,y):
hd = z
hs = y
try:
sd = hd/hs
except ZeroDivisionError as err
print "this cannot be possible".err
```

And when i called the function `exceptionhandling(1,0)` i didnt get the expected output "this cannot be possible".

PLease help me in understanding this one ..Am new to so so am sorry if this is a low standard one.

Comment: What is the output you get? I'd expect a SyntaxError or IndentationError.

Comment: Look at the fixed code and add a ":" at the end of the except line.

Comment: I've edited your answer and now it contains right indentations. But you've also had problem with output exception. @zhangxaochen answer's good as for me for debug or log, but mine more useful for users's output

Comment: @Ant, do not fix code in questions, that is the purpose of answers.

Comment: @Matthias its shows the same error ?..huh ?

Comment: @OGHaza I thought it was a mistake in question formatting

Answer (score 0):

You try to call err method of string. Actually, it doesn't has it)
Better way to do this is

```
print "this cannot be possible %s" % err.message
```

Also I hope that you don't forget about indentations.

Comment: Use 4 spaces(or tab if it equals to 4 spaces) to make indents like in @zhangxaochen's answer. No indent before def, one before hd = z and other and two before sd = ... and print ...

Answer (score 0):

There exists some typos in your code:

```
#first indent your code correctly
def exceptionhandling(z,y):
    hd = z
    hs = y
    try:
        sd = hd/hs 
        return sd #return the result if you get it without exception
    except ZeroDivisionError as err: #need ":" at the end of line
        print "this cannot be possible", err  #print multiple strings with commas
```

running demo:

```
In [59]: exceptionhandling(0, 3) #0/3 is ok 

In [60]: exceptionhandling(4, 0) #4/0 is not allowed
this cannot be possible integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: yes i didnt get any error here ..but i didnt get the output ..and when i called the function exceptionhandling(0,1) it didnt prints out  "this cannot be possible"

Comment: You should `return sd` if you want output. And `0/1 == 0`, you need the zero on the denominator to raise an error.

Comment: @user3356408 here? where? exceptionhandling(0,1) is ok, exceptionhandling(1, 0) is wrong in your case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe seems the OP just want to learn exception handling ;), anyway, updated

Answer (score 0):

You will get `err` as exception object, you can get the detail value of that using `err.args`.

`args` is tuple of 2 element, first is code and second is description.